# nth of type based on dynamic class

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have made a simplified version here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y5zYy/

I'm trying to add a different css style to the nth visible item of a list, so when the user clicks on group2 for example, I want the third Item of that group to turn black(Which is number 4), while currently the second item, which is the 3rd item of the whole list turns black.

Here is how it works:
When you click on each group, items on that group will be added a class say "visible"
then I want javascript to count visible items after each click and add some style to the nth visible item regardless of its number in the whole list.

### HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="g1">1</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">2</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">3</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">4</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">5</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">6</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">7</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">8</li>
    <li class="g1 g2">9</li>
    <li class="g1 g2 g3">10</li>
    <li class="g1 g2 g3">11</li>
</ul>
<a id="g1" href=#>Group1</a>
<a id="g2" href=#>Group2</a>
<a id="g3" href=#>Group3</a>
```

### JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){


         $('li:nth-of-type(3)').css({
                                  "background-color":"#000",
                                   "font-weight":"bold",

      })



 $("li").addClass("visible");
$("a").click(function() {
             $("li").removeClass("visible");
             $('li').css({
                 "background-color":"red"
                                      })
               $(this).each(function() {
     $("." + $(this).attr('id')).addClass("visible");
   });
       if( $('li.visible').length > 3 ){
         $('li:nth-of-type(3)').css({
                                  "background-color":"#000",
                                   "font-weight":"bold",

      })
}
        });

});//]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to target the 3rd `<li>` element in the group after hiding the rest, then you should use the `:eq()` selector in jQuery:

```
$('li:eq(2)').css({
    "background-color": "#000",
    "font-weight": "bold"
});
```

eq() starts from 0, so if you want to select the 3rd `<li>` you'll need to use `:eq(2)`

If you want to toggle the appearance of the element, may I recommend adding and removing classes, which makes it easier to reset to the default style when not needed:

```
$('li.visible:eq(2)').addClass('highlighted');
```

CSS:

```
.highlighted {
    background-color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I didn't get it, I still get the wrong element highlighted using the eq selector

Comment: Should it be `$('li.visible:eq(2)').addClass('highlighted')`? You only want to count visible items.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, this seems to work, but there is one problem, if the group contains exactly 3 items, the third one wont get highlighted, here is the fiddle, try clicking on Group3: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5zYy/1/

Comment: That is because of this conditional statement - `if( $('li.visible').length > 3 )` You should set it to `> 2` instead. Remember that JS counts from 0 onwards.